# Ошибка No ST-LINK detected. STM32F103C8

Tags: stm32

Купил новый STM32F103C8. Начинаю прошивать, вижу, что его не определяет J-Link:

```
J-Link connection not established yet but required for command.
Connecting to J-Link via USB...FAILED: Failed to open DLL
```

Решил обновить ST-Link до J-Link'a, вроде нормально прошивается

```
Preparing for FW update (can take up to 10 seconds)...O.K.
Identifying ST-LINK variant...O.K.: ST-LINK/V2
Performing firmware update...O.K.
```

Но J-Link его также не видит.

Захожу в ST-Link Utility и получаю следующее:

```
00:41:07 : No ST-LINK detected
00:41:39 : Can not connect to target!
                  Please select "Connect Under Reset" mode from Target->Settings menu and try again.
                  If you're trying to connect to a low frequency application , please select a lower SWD Frequency mode from Target->Settings menu.
00:41:41 : STLink USB communication error
```

При этом, диспетчер устройств все определяет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И до этого я к МК вообще не притрагивался. Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема.

Comment: Обновлял до J-Link'a этим https://yadi.sk/d/tX90S8YBz5y8y (STLinkReflash.exe ver. STLinkReflashFixed.exe). Подключал через ST-Link V2 Programmer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вдруг у кого-нибудь такая же проблема будет, обновите прошивку ST-LINK Utility

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]